# mongodb Live migration from replicaset

Tags: mongodb, database-migration, replicaset

I would like to migrate away from my current mlab to a self hosted replicaset. Rather than shut down everything and use a mongoimport/export I would like to do a live migration as described here: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/import/live-import/ Is this possible if you're not using atlas? How would I go about it? Thanks.

Comment: It's not pretty.  The live-import tool does many of the same things as an initial sync, and then copies oplog events and applies them in the other cluster.  I'm not even sure how that might be done without writing a tool that can include some of the mongod source files.

Comment: @Joe after googling around I found the tool atlas made, mongomirror. The documentation indicates it's for atlas but I think it's hinted that it can be used for other hosts as well. Is the live-import tool you're talking about that or is there something else I haven't seen yet? Thanks.

Comment: That's the tool I was thinking of, I wasn't aware that it was able to connect outside of Atlas.  I don't see its source code in a public repo, so I'm not really sure.

Comment: @Joe darn it, they got me. Decided to use Atlas... lol.